# How to remove trailing zeros from lightning input LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

I read through the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) but didn't find an answer, I tried to use the [lightning-formatted-number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/example) element, but it's only used for display and can't be edited as far as I can tell.

expected: 123

actual: 123.00

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/A7zhdYC6/1/edit)

Comment: whats wrong with setting step="0" if you want 123?

Comment: haha nothing, I missed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Just Set the step as "0" like

```
<template>
        <lightning-input type="number" name="input7" label="Number field with currency formatter" value="123" formatter="currency" step="0"></lightning-input>
</template>
```